# Exercise of functions of a real variable

Tags: functions, inequality, functional-equations

> Let $f, g\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ functions so that for all $\,x, y\in\mathbb{R}$,  $$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)g(y).$$ Prove that if $f$ is not constant zero function and $|f(x)|\leqslant 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$  then  $|g(x)|\leqslant 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $|f|\leqslant 1$ can be removed by a homogeneity argument (we actually just need $f$ bounded). We have for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$ that 
$$2|f(x)|\cdot |g(y)|\leqslant 2\sup_{t\in\Bbb R}|f(t)|,$$
and taking the supremum over $x\in\Bbb R$, this gives 
$$\sup_{t\in\Bbb R}|f(t)|\cdot |g(y)|\leqslant \sup_{t\in\Bbb R}|f(t)|.$$
We can divide by $\sup_{t\in\Bbb R}|f(t)|$ as $f$ does identically vanish.